# Sailsjs + vuejs + axios + CSRF tokens

Tags: vue.js, sails.js, axios, csrf, http-status-code-403

i some thing not understand. Always get an error 403. I have a code in frontend(vue.js), here I get a token _csrf from Sails.js, its ok.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:1337/csrfToken')
        .then(response => {

            this.$store.commit('csrf_update', response.data._csrf);
            console.log("_csrf===",response.data._csrf);
            axios.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-Token'] = response.data._csrf;
        })
```

And i have a backend sails.js, settings in security.js

```
cors: {
 allRoutes: true,
 allowOrigins: 'http://localhost:8080',
 allowCredentials: false,
 allowRequestMethods:'GET, POST',
 allowRequestHeaders:'content-type, X-CSRF-Token'}, csrf: true
```

i have a token like that `_csrf: lM8avM1X-KvKz9v2zLnbQZFf8lKOThX9Llb4`
And i have error 403 when request.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:1337/login', form)
    .then(response => {
        this.$router.push('/kabinet');
    }).catch(error => { console.log(error); });
```

[list 403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P7Xv.jpg)

thats my Headers

[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXurr.jpg)

what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, everything was very simple. 
In the (sails.js) file security.js to change `allowCredentials: false` on `allowCredentials: true`, and in frontend (vue.js) change axion, add parameter `withCredentials: true` like this

```
axios.get('http://localhost:1337/csrfToken',{ 
withCredentials: true
}).then(response => {
            console.log("_csrf===",response.data._csrf);
            axios.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-Token'] = response.data._csrf;
})
```

and in all axios requests must be `withCredentials: true`

Answer (score 1):

Sails has a property called csrf in the config>security file. If you set it on true you can simply add

`<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %> />`

to your form or at the place where you need it.

I am on sails 1.0.2 and it works quiet good.

Answer (score 0):

In the headers of the axios request add:

"x-csrf-token": window.SAILS_LOCALS._csrf